# Need a help on truncating

Tags: truncate

Hellow Guys,

I need to give an idea on a simple program.

Write a function which shortens a string to n characters. If the string is already shorter than n, the function should not change the string. Assume the prototype is

```
void truncate(char *str, int inLen);
```

just give a simple explanation ..

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect us to do your job?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. The [help/on-topic] says *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*** Good luck.

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort homework dump. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tried somelogic of your own so now i can give your problem a try in c here

```
void truncate(char *str, int inLen){
    int len=strlen(str);
    char *newstr;
    newstr=(char *)malloc(inLen*sizeof(char));
    if(inLen>len)
        strcpy(newstr,str);
    else{
        strncpy(newstr,str,inLen);
    }
    printf("%s",newstr);
}
```

A C++ Solution here :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void truncate(char *str, int inLen){
    int len=strlen(str);
    char *newstr=new char[inLen];
    if(inLen>len)
        strcpy(newstr,str);
    else{
        strncpy(newstr,str,inLen);
    }
    cout<<newstr;
}
int main()
{
char str[100];
int inLen;
cin>>inLen;
cin>>str;
truncate(str,inLen);
return 0;
}
```

Python here :

```
string=input("Enter string")
inLen=int(input("Enter trim length"))
newstring=string[0:inLen]
print(newstring)
```

Comment: Thanks Shahil Jain

Comment: Please upvote incase you found it helpfull :)

Comment: I can't upvote. But tick as helpful.. To upvote more 15 reputation needed..

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>

void truncateCharArray(int maxLength , char * inLen )
{
if ((0 == inLen) || !(0 < maxLength))
return;
cout<<"To my eye, this is confusing. Why not simply"<<endl;

if (inLen == NULL || maxLength <= 0)
return;
if (maxLength < strlen(inLen))
cout<<"What if maxLength is equal to the length of buffer?"<<endl;
{
inLen[maxLength] = '\0';
}
return;
}

int main()
{
    truncateCharArray(30,'dsd');
    return 0;
}


That what I have already tried.
```